# distribution upgrade 14.04 to 15.04 halted due to multiple errors

Tags: upgrade, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

During distribution upgrade 14.04 to 15.04, process halts due to many `dpkg` errors, here are a few of them.

```
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 gnome-bluetooth
 systemd
 ubuntu-minimal
 bluez
 indicator-bluetooth
 python3-checkbox-support
 python3-checkbox-ng
 pulseaudio
 plainbox-provider-checkbox
 mountall
 unity-control-center
 alsa-base
 libcanberra-pulse:amd64
 pulseaudio-module-x11
 libsolid4
 initramfs-tools
 udisks2
 plainbox-provider-resource-generic
 upower
 media-player-info
 unity-control-center-signon
 plymouth
 indicator-power
 network-manager
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 kdelibs5-plugins
 gnome-user-share
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
 software-properties-gtk
 indicator-sound
 indicator-network
 rhythmbox
 ubuntu-desktop
 gnome-disk-utility
 lightdm
 upstart
 libconnectivity-qt1:amd64
 gnome-session-bin
 brltty
 linux-image-4.2.0-36-generic
 ubuntu-system-settings
 dolphin4
 unity-greeter
 linux-image-generic
 checkbox-ng
 checkbox-ng-service
 libkio5
 konqueror
 checkbox-gui
 gnome-power-manager
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is no longer supported, what did you use to do the upgrade?

Comment: the notification from ubuntu that said ubuntu upgrade available

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't saying `16.04`? Try executing from terminal `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and finally `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`.

Comment: this is the message back, as it is not configured the package apt
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for xxx: 
apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.16: symbol _ZTVNSt7__cxx1119basic_istringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference